# How can I use layout_weight in RecyclerView or ListView item view to have items of equal height fill up the available space on screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I currently have a need to use a RecyclerView (or ListView) but the number of items is fixed at 4. I want those 4 items to equally use the available space on the screen. The RecyclerView is the only view on the screen except for the app bar. I.e. RecyclerView has `layout_height` set to `match_parent`. I chose the RecyclerView because the items have different layouts depending on model state.

I haven't looked it up yet, but I'm sure I can set the height programmatically in Java code for each item. But that seems inelegant if I can specify it in the XML. Similar questions to my right, as I write this, answer that question.

I've tried the following in the item_layout.xml file, the way `layout_weight` is used in other scenarios:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">...</LinearLayout>
```

But then nothing shows on screen.

What I'd like to know is, **can I do this in the layout XML with `layout_weight`, or something else? If so, how?**

Comment: if the number of views is fixed. I completely discourage you to use listview. just put for linear layout with weight equal to one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As the [API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) says, `layout_weight` is an attribute of `LinearLayout`, so it **cannot** be used with other ViewGroups like, for instance, `RecyclerView` and `ListView`. Instead, you have to set the item's height programmatically.

Since you seem worried about your code's cleanliness, I think this is a rather elegant solution in case you use a `RecyclerView`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

    int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / 4;
    int width = parent.getMeasuredWidth();

    view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(width, height));

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: `parent.getMeasuredHeight()` returns '0' value!

Comment: Is `getMeasuredHeight` the problem here?

Comment: For those having parent.getMeasuredSomething. maybe, you have your recyclerview have a wrap_content so it will initially have 0 height and the succeeding views will be adjusted to that.

Comment: @josemigallas I am getting '0' for both height and width.  MyRecyclerview has width set as "match_parent" and height as "wrap_content" . For the adapter xml file, both width and height are wrap_content. Any help would be appreciated here thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Try this, work for me

```
int weight = 3; //number of parts in the recycler view. 

@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        rowView.getLayoutParams().height = parent.getHeight() / weight;
        return new ViewHolder(rowView);
    }
```

Comment: you have a syntax error, it should be parent.getContext(), the edit it too small for me to change.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. parent.getHeight() is -2.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue, as I had a RecyclerView with variable entries. My horizontal RecyclerView needed to fit at least three views without overflowing, so I constructed my views to be resized at runtime to fit the screen.

```
class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    int mViewWidth;

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context) {
      mViewWidth = defineViewWidth(context);
    }

    private int defineViewWidth(Context context) {
      int definedWidth = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_view_width);
      DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
      WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
      wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
      if (definedWidth * 3 > dm.widthPixels) {
        return dm.widthPixels / 3;
      }
      return definedWidth;
    }

    ...

}
```

Once you have a width defined, you need to set the view width:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = mViewWidth;
    v.setLayoutParams(params);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

You could easily modify this to make sure your RecyclerView fits as many elements (vertically or horizontally) as you need.

Answer (score 1):

It could be simply accomplished using a custom ItemDecoration:

```
class SameLinearSpaceItemDecoration(
        private val minSpanCount: Int = 1
        , private val paddingHorizontal: Int = 0
        , private val paddingVertical: Int = 0
) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

        if (parent.layoutManager !is LinearLayoutManager) return

        val spanCount = (Math.max(minSpanCount, parent.adapter?.itemCount ?: 1))
        if ((parent.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).orientation == RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL) {
            view.layoutParams.width = (parent.measuredWidth - paddingHorizontal - paddingHorizontal) / spanCount
        } else { // vertical
            view.layoutParams.height = (parent.measuredHeight - paddingVertical - paddingVertical) / spanCount
        }

        view.setPadding(if (paddingHorizontal == 0) view.paddingLeft else paddingHorizontal
                , if (paddingVertical == 0) view.paddingTop else paddingVertical
                , if (paddingHorizontal == 0) view.paddingRight else paddingHorizontal
                , if (paddingVertical == 0) view.paddingBottom else paddingVertical)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By ItemDecoration:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
    int itemWidth = parent.getMeasuredWidth() / 7;
    view.getLayoutParams().width = itemWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue just to keep items in horizontal recycleView spread equally which means each of them has an equal space, here is my CircleItemDecoration (in `Kotlin`):

```
class CircleItemDecoration() : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        Timber.d("parent.width = ${parent.width} outRect = ${view.width}")
        val itemCount = parent.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0
        if (itemCount <= 1) return
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) != 0) {
            outRect.left = (parent.width - view.width * itemCount) / (itemCount - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

and one trick for this is we need to "addItemDecoration" in doOnPreDraw,
which ensure the measure of each UI element has been calculated:

```
rvSpeedControl.doOnPreDraw {
    rvSpeedControl.addItemDecoration(CircleItemDecoration())
}
```