# How to always show full items not part of items in Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android development 
I have a Recyclerview and I want it to always show items with full layout not part of the item when screen size is changed!

say I have a Recyclerview that shows 3 items vertically in XXXhdpi when I changed the device with smaller screen (for example the new device's screen size is XXhdpi) the recyclerview shows 2 items and part of the 3rd Item and you have to scroll to see the whole item...
how to avoid this problem and always show the 3 items or maybe 2 items ! what i care about is to always show the whole item that fits in the screen not part of it.

if the screen can fit 2 items then the 3rd item should not be showed and the 2 items that appear should have bigger width and height to fit in the screen and hide the space of the 3rd item.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432261/list-view-snap-to-item. I think this is what you want.

Comment: @Apoorv I don't think that's his problem

Comment: @Apoorv That's not my problem...I want recyclerview's Item layout to fully appear in the screen when there is a space to be fully showed and disappear when no space is available to be FULLY showed.

Comment: I found a smart and simple solution in this link : [using on onCreateViewHolder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37660180/6616185)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's say `single_row.xml` is the layout that is repeated in the recylcerview
You will have to create separate `single_row.xml` layouts for various screen sizes. And they will be accordingly used during the `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: How do you decide the height though? A 4.5 inch device with 720x1280 falls in xhdpi and 10.1 inch device with 2560x1600 also falls in xhdpi.

Comment: As you pointed out the height of the device has no direct relation with resolution. You will have to test out on various devices to understand whether your recyclerview sits properly. Try using genymotion as an android emulator for this purpose.

Comment: learn from some tutorial about layouts for various screen sizes to get an idea about what I am talking about.

Comment: @suku do you have any example or can you provide a code block that can help me to understand your point!

Comment: @suku That was a very useful youtube clip to help me understand my problem reason ! although i found a great simple and smart solution using onCreateViewHolder in this link [linl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37660180/6616185)

Comment: @suku I just noticed that you mentioned using onCreateViewHolder in your answer!

Thank you

Comment: You can't practically do this for two main reasons. 1. Your view will have different dimens on different devices, 2. If your content is dynamic having different layout files for different screen sizes will make no sense