# Space Recyclerview items evenly (horizontally)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_profile_selection_dim_bg"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#80000000">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text=".."
            android:textColor=".."
            android:textSize="17.3sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Recyclerview fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="11.6sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using recyclerviews `GridManagerLayout` (3 columns). I would like to do this using xml attributes, if possible, but I'm open to other ideas, of course. And, of course, some explanation would be great as well - I want to understand my problem not only solve it. :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to set your textview width same as ImageView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="11.6sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `TextView` width( `wrap_content` to `50dp`) in  **recyclerView** row.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="11.6sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Because of this - text aligns perfectly with imageview, but STILL recyclerview last element has bigger space between itself and layout edge

Comment: only problem with last item ?Now i updated my code check it  @JoshuaMad

Comment: Every rows last element.. :( It's like elements in row doesnt fill up all horizontal space.

Comment: you can also use android:maxLength="20" . It will fix your length.

Comment: It would limit textview, but the spacing problem is not on textview, but on whole recyclerview item (last one).

Comment: You can set your parent layout height and width as 50dp .I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="50dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:gravity="center_vertical"
>     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>     android:focusable="true"
>     android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="50dp"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     `/>
> </LinearLayout>
>
> Change your parent layout width as a 50dp
> Hope this will help you
> ```

Answer (score 0):

this answer it worked with me I divide by 3 for width 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660180/9612786

see my code:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item, parent, false);

    //int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight();
    int width = parent.getMeasuredWidth() / 3;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 16,0, 16);

    view.setLayoutParams(params);


    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
```